# Cannot center progressDrawable over background in progressBar

Tags: java, android, xml, progress-bar, graphical-logo

I'm trying to create a progressBar using a image with text on it (actually the image is a text logo saved as png).

I already created a normal progressBar using 2 images (a gray one as background and a blue one as the progress bar) and it worked just fine.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pbLoading"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
    android:background="@drawable/grayloadingbar"
    android:progress="@integer/loadingProgress"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress"
    android:radius="0dp"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

This is the custom_progress.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/blueloadingbar"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        <corners android:radius="0dp" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The problem is that replacing those 2 images with other images (the text logo images mentioned above), this doesn't look good anymore.

The loading works just fine and I can see the progress but the progress bar image seams to be having a fixed size while the background src is variable, depending on the display and I can resize it myself, something I cannot do for the progress bar.

Here is the XML:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pbLoading"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="68dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
    android:background="@drawable/loading_bw"
    android:minHeight="20dip"
    android:mirrorForRtl="false"
    android:progress="@integer/fullProgress"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress"
    android:radius="0dp"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

And the custom_progress

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/loading_color"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp" />
        <corners android:radius="0dp" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I cannot show you the images but the whole progress bar looks like it has
100% width & height and 25dp margin top & left, if you take the top-left corner of the background image as a reference point.

Any ideas?

I've been digging a lot for this and no luck so far.

Comment: So the summary of this would be you need to center your progress bar?

Comment: Sort of. The idea is to have bot images one on top of another so that the blue images gradually shows up making the use think the gray text on the image is gradually becoming blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add theme to your progress bar like 
Make a layout surround your progress bar eg: a relativeLayout place your progressbar inside it and then apply this tag to the layout.
So the layout having progressbar now will be adjusted as a dialog.

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Dialog"
```

**Second method**

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();  
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Apply the above width/2 and height/2 as the width and height of your progress bar.

**Method 3**

If you want the display dimensions in pixels you can use getSize:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

Apply the above width/2 and height/2 as the width and height of your progress bar.But as these dimensions will be in pixels.So adjust them accordingly.

**NOTE:**

> Method 3 works with ApiLevel :13 and above only.